# How to add dynamic data during run time in array of dictionary object in react native

Tags: react-native

I am making an react native android application in which i am using google maps.I am also using markers in now google maps.Now the data in markers array are added during runtime.The format for markers array is like this.

```
markers: [{
                title: 'hello',
                coordinates: {
                  latitude: 3.148561,
                  longitude: 101.652778
                },
              },
              {
                title: 'hello',
                coordinates: {
                  latitude: 3.149771,
                  longitude: 101.655449
                },  
              }]
```

But since i am adding data during run time .I have put marker : [] in state .
After fetching latitude and longitude of every location in markers array like this.

```
var lat = _location.lat
var long = _location.lng
const array = [...this.state.markers_two];
array[i] = { ...array[i], title:location};

array[i] = { ...array[i], coordinates: {latitude:lat,longitude:long}};

this.setState({ markers_two: array });
```

But above does not works.I also tried like this.

```
var arr = this.state.markers_two


arr.push({title:location,coordinates:{latitude:lat,longitude:long}})

this.setState({ markers_two: arr });
```

But this also does not works.So what i am doing wrong?How can i add all the recieved location data in markers array?

Comment: Can you show your exact code? Especially the method in which you receive the data and set the state. Because from what you've shown there shouldn't be any problems.

Comment: What about `this.setState({ markers: [...this.state.markers, { title: location, coordinates: { latitude: _location.lat, longitude: _location.long }}]})`?

Comment: Could it be because you are calling one `markers` and the other `markers_two`?